# Javascript: Catch an element using "getElementsByTagName"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, 2d

I have a javascript canavas code where if I catch the tag "Canvas" with ID, its starts working, but if i catch it using "TagName" it stop working.

in my code Canvas tag is generating at runtime and I cannot pass the ID for the same so I want to generate the 2D object on Canvas by catching it with tagname.

Here is the code for the same:

**JS**

```
    var canvas=document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
    var context=canvas.getContext("2d");

    function Line(x1,y1,x2,y2){
        this.x1=x1;
        this.y1=y1;
        this.x2=x2;
        this.y2=y2;
    }
    Line.prototype.drawWithArrowheads=function(ctx){

        // arbitrary styling
        ctx.strokeStyle="blue";
        ctx.fillStyle="blue";
        ctx.lineWidth=1;

        // draw the line
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(this.x1,this.y1);
        ctx.lineTo(this.x2,this.y2);
        ctx.stroke();

        // draw the starting arrowhead
        var startRadians=Math.atan((this.y2-this.y1)/(this.x2-this.x1));
        startRadians+=((this.x2>this.x1)?-90:90)*Math.PI/180;
        this.drawArrowhead(ctx,this.x1,this.y1,startRadians);
        // draw the ending arrowhead
        var endRadians=Math.atan((this.y2-this.y1)/(this.x2-this.x1));
        endRadians+=((this.x2>this.x1)?90:-90)*Math.PI/180;
        this.drawArrowhead(ctx,this.x2,this.y2,endRadians);

    }
    Line.prototype.drawArrowhead=function(ctx,x,y,radians){
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.translate(x,y);
        ctx.rotate(radians);
        ctx.moveTo(0,0);
        ctx.lineTo(5,20);
        ctx.lineTo(-5,20);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.restore();
        ctx.fill();
    }

    // create a new line object
    var line=new Line(50,50,250,275);
    // draw the line
    line.drawWithArrowheads(context);
```

**Here is the Fiddle for the same: http://jsfiddle.net/Sg7EZ/179/**

Let me know if you need any other information.

Please suggest.

Comment: "not working" should not appear in a title. Use the space wisely to quickly summarize the actual issue. This would be much easier to do if the issue *was* clearly described in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want to change

```
document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
```

to this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
```

This way you will get the first element (and only one in this case) instead of the nodelist (which doesn't have a `getContext` function)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sg7EZ/180/)

The better alternative would actually be to use the ID on your canvas element and use something like `getElementById("canvas")` so you know for sure exactly what element you are using (in case you ever end up with multiple canvas elements).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sg7EZ/182/)

Comment: Thanks!! Regarding the second option I agree its always better to use "ID", but like I mentioned in my question, in my actual code, Canvas is generating at run time and I cannot pass the ID also at runtime , So i was looking for the option of Tag Name... but Nice explanation.. I learnt new thing today! :-)

Answer (score 3):

[getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), while [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) returns an [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element). Try `canvas[0].getContext("2d")` to return the first instance of canvas.

Comment: I agree, the code didnt work when I changed to "canvas.getContext("2d")[0]", but it works when I changed to "canvas[0].getContext("2d")"... but thanks for explaining the issue!